# how to add "create node form" in a block?

Tags: forms, blocks, nodes

I just wanted to know how to add "create node form" in a block

when i  copy the source code and make a block out of that code, **only public** could post from that.
when i am posting **as a user** it says timeout and tells us to refresh the page.
plz someone give me solution.

SO i tried to add the following code in page.tpl.php

```
$form = node_add('nodetype');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Answer (score 3):

there are two modules which can give option to create node from block
[Formblock module](https://drupal.org/project/formblock) ,
[Advanced Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/afb)

Answer (score 1):

> function mymodulename_block_info() {
>
> ```
> $blocks['mymodulename_node_form'] = array(
>     'info' => t('Post a Node'), 
>     'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
> );
> return $blocks;
> ```
>
> }

/** Implements hook_block_view() */

> function mymodulename_block_view($delta = ''){
>
> ```
>  switch ($delta) {
>     case 'mymodulename_node_form':
>         $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('mymodulename_node_form');
>         //$block['content'] = block_contents($delta);
>         break;
> }
> return $block;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code in your template file.

```
if (!function_exists('node_add')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this in response to another question. This is what you would place into a custom module. Alternately, you could try Advanced Form Block module as mentioned (I haven't yet), which as of today is still supported.

For people still having trouble with their code when using anything AJAX-related (e.g. 500 errors) or simply trying to open up the 'blocks' tab in Panels without some error (e.g. some Entity Translation functions) you might want to try the following module code instead in Drupal 7 (but some parameters may still need to be added for your purposes).

```
function custom_example_block_info() {

    $blocks['example_node_form'] = array(
       'info' => t('What an example'), 
    );
    return $blocks; 

}

function custom_example_block_view($delta = ''){

    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'example_node_form':
            global $user;
            //Note: 'type' is your node content type and 'language' must be included
            $node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'example', 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);

            $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);

            form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
            $block['content'] = drupal_build_form('example_node_form', $form_state);

            break;
    }
return $block; 

}
```

The important difference is that drupal_get_form cannot load the $form_state so we use function form_load_include(&$form_state, $type, $module, $name = NULL) to ensure the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed and function drupal_build_form($form_id, &$form_state) instead of drupal_get_form to pass $form_state. The lines above create the $form_state.